# SQL Server Permissions and Ownership Chaining

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2008-r2

I am building an application consisting of an SQL Server 2008 R2 back-end and an MS Access front-end.
All data is kept in SQL Server.
MS Access is a just a bunch of forms, controls and VBA ADO objects that call stored procedures on the SQL server, ie. users interface with SQL server through stored procedures only.
These stored procedures are a combination of ones that don't alter the state of the database (eg. select from table/view/function) and some that do alter state (eg. insert/update/delete/merge)

On SQL Server, I have an AD Group called 'ADG', which is both a Server Login and a Database User.  Users of the MS Access front-end are members of ADG.
All of the SQL Server database objects (tables, views, functions and stored procedures) are under a single, specific schema called 'ABC' that is owned by dbo.  There are other schemas in the database, again, all owned by dbo.

I have been reading up on 'Ownership Chaining' and would like clarification of the following:

1. Is 'dbo' the 'owner' of the tables, views, functions and stored procedure under the 'ABC' schema by virtue of its ownership of the 'ABC' schema?
2. Given the above set up of the application and depending on the answer to 1., is 'EXECUTE' on the ABC schema, the only permission I
   need granted to ADG or do I need any others?

Any help in clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465.aspx for a good picture of the permission hierarchy.

1. If all your objects are in the same ABC schema, then the owner of the schema is effectively the owner of the underlying objects. Again, see the diagram in the link above for a clear picture.

   2. EXECUTE is a specific permission to execute stored procedures. You can do the same for functions unless the function returns a table, then you need SELECT permissions. So if you GRANT EXECUTE on SCHEMA::ABC TO adg then you've just allowed adg to run sprocs. They still may not have access to data depending on how the sprocs were written. Look up details on permissions in SQL Server books online for details on what you need to grant (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx)